# Scala variable is not working in intellij

Tags: scala

I have declared the following variable, it's working fine in Scala console.

```
val \u0041=12
A: Int = 12
```

Getting can't resolve error message, when i tried in Intellij.
I am using Scala 2.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It just shown by the intellij because according to intellij its not correct declaration but when you compile you sbt or maven project from terminal it will compile successfully. Even you can also compile it by intellij Build -> make or compile it will not shown compilation error.Its just intellij editor problem.